# sympy symbols $Delta x$

Tags: latex, sympy

I want to declare a symbol like $Delta x$, rendered as latex in the print. But `x= sympy.symbols('Delta x')` does not work and also with `\\Delta x` or `\Delta x` but for some reason `Delta_x` works printing x as underscore.

Comment: no doesn't work for me, i tried `\Delta x`

Comment: @user23657 - That other answer suggested that you should use `Symbol` (capital `S` at the start and no `s` at the end) instead of `symbols`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks i didn't noticed that, it worked:)